# How to use class in Callable Args Type List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made class `PassedData(TypedDict)` which I'm trying to use as in a type argument list for `Callable`:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Type, TypedDict

class PassedData(TypedDict):
    node: str
    
class Action(TypedDict):
    action: Callable[PassedData, Any]
    data: Any
```

But doing I get an error that `PassedData` is not a valid type argument for `Callable`. So I thought I might need to use `Type` to create a new type `IsPassedData`:

```py
class PassedData(TypedDict):
    node: str

IsPassedData = Type(PassedData)

class Action(TypedDict):
    action: Callable[IsPassedData, Any]
    data: Any
```

But this gives me the same error as before...that IsPassedData is not a valid type argument. What's the correct way to add this type argument to `Callable`?

Comment: `Callable[[PassedData], Any]`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the type of the action `action: Callable[PassedData, Any]`.

It should be `action: Callable[[PassedData], Any]` note that the `PassedData` is in an array, it indicates that the action field should be a `Callable` that takes one argument: an instance of `PassedData` and returns `Any` type